Django Postgres Json Filtering
there is a django model Model. It has a JSONField type field.
There are approximately 1000 json files in postgresql in the table of this model.
Json has a strict structure. 'food' -> foodid -> 'field' -> fieldname -> {....}. There can be arbitrary values instead of foodid and fieldname.
How do I get unique possible pairs (foodid, fieldname) from postgres?
Model.objects.annotate(
 foodid=Func(
 F('food'),
 function='jsonb_object_keys',
 output_field=models.CharField()
 )
 ).annotate(
 field_name=Func(
 Value('food__') + F('foodid') + Value('__field'), 
 function='jsonb_object_keys',
 output_field=models.CharField()
 )
 ).values_list('food_id', 'field_names')

The first annotate works. In the second annotate, I want to take the food_id field from the first annotate, but simply specifying F('foodidid__field'), the postgres will look for the foodid field in the table itself which does not exist.

from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL

Model.objects.annotate(
  foodid=RawSQL("jsonb_object_keys(food)", []),
  fieldname=RawSQL("jsonb_object_keys((food -> jsonb_object_keys(food)::text) -> 'field')", [])
).values('foodid', 'fieldname').distinct()

This will allow you to efficiently retrieve the unique (foodid, fieldname) pairs from your JSON field in PostgreSQL. If you encounter any issues or the JSON structure varies slightly, let me know, and I’ll help you refine the query
